# Regex failing to match inner repeatable occurrences

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm failing to match a nested capturing group multiple times, the result only gives me the *last* inner capture instead.

Input string: `=F2=0B=E2some text =C2=A3`
Regex: `(\=([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]))+`

The capturing groups it returns is:

Group 1:

- `=F2=0B=E2`
- `=C2=A3`

Group 2:

- `E2`
- `A3`

---

But I need Group 2 to return:

- `F2`
- `0B`
- `E2`

and

- `C2`
- `A3`

within each outer group.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: What is the programming language? Note that you cannot get those `F2`, `0B` values in Group2, you could get them in Group2 *Captures*.

Comment: @stribizhev .NET C# actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to access the `match.Groups[2].Captures` collection.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3D(%5B0-9A-F%5D%7B2%7D))%2B&i=%3DF2%3D0B%3DE2some%20text%20%3DC2%3DA3)

[image]

What you need is a [*CaptureCollection*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection(v=vs.110).aspx). See this [`Regex.Match` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **`Captures`** 
>   Gets a collection of all the captures matched by the capturing group, in innermost-leftmost-first order (or innermost-rightmost-first order if the regular expression is modified with the `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` option). The collection may have zero or more items.(Inherited from Group.)

Here is a [sample demo](http://ideone.com/sDph9M) that outputs all the captures from `Groups[2]` CaptureCollection (`F2`, `0B`, `E2`, `C2`, `A3`):

```
var pattern = "(=([0-9A-F]{2}))+";
var result = Regex.Matches("=F2=0B=E2some text =C2=A3", pattern)
          .Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[2].Captures)
          .ToList();
foreach (var coll in result)
   foreach (var v in coll)
        Console.WriteLine(v);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So this only possible in .NET then?

Comment: From what I know, it is also possible in PyPi Python *regex* module, but I have never used that. Just note I contracted your regex a bit using a limiting quantifier `{2}` in order not to repeat `[0-9A-F]`.